# Radarchart with log10 transformation

Tags: r, radar-chart

I'm using `radarchart` in the `fmsb` package, and I need to plot some of the variables on a log scale. The package itself doesn't seem to have built-in support. Has anyone done a workaround for this?

Thanks so much!

```
library(fmsb)
sub <- structure(list(Methane = c(100, 0.001, 10), `Dissolved Oxygen, field measured` = c(5, 0, 5), `Iron` = c(10, 0.1, 1.3), 
    `Nitrate as N` = c(10, 0.01, 0.1), `Sulfate` = c(25, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


radarchart(sub)
```

Comment: Both `Dissolved Oxygen` and `Sulfate` contain zero values.  How are you going to take logs?

Comment: Sorry, should've specified - log scales for some of the variables, specifically - methane, iron, and nitrate